# iPhone: change cell layout upon selection

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Application presents a list of items. Every item can be presented in either basic or extended mode. Extended mode provides more details about that item and has its own layout defined by a stand-alone XIB file. Multiple items can be selected. The layouts have to be switched upon selection/deselection of the item.

I am implementing the list using UITableView. The problem is that the cell gets redrawn only if it's scrolled out and then back into the screen. How do I fix that?

Here is what I am doing now:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell =[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ExtendedCellId];
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell =[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CollapsedCellId];
}
```

Comment: try adding `[cell setNeedsDisplay]` after your modifications - this will force it to be redrawn in the next draw cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `[cell setNeedsDisplay]` after your modifications - this will force it to be redrawn in the next draw cycle.

EDIT: If the height changes I think you have to reload the table view or those cells.  Once you've modified your cells, you can try the basic update calls:

```
 [tableView beginUpdates];
 [tableView endUpdates];
```

If that doesn't work, you probably want to try putting a specific reload between the `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` call -

```
 [tableView beginUpdates];
 [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:<indexPath here> withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
 [tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: I've tried both 'setNeedsDisplay' and 'setNeedsLayout' with and without 'begin/endUpdates' - does not work. 'reload...' makes the table to forget what was selected and prevents it from calling 'didDeselect'

Comment: when you call reload, are you reloading the whole table, just that row, or the section?

Comment: tried reload the entire table and specific rows (reloadData and reloadRowsAtIndexPaths)

Comment: Yeah it can be iffy sometimes as to what triggers the proper redraw - one last thing I would try is to reload the section with `reloadSections:withRowAnimation:`

Comment: OK, reloadSections does it! However, it reloads the entire table (there is only one section). So I guess I need to put every item into a separate section to make it work properly. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Yeah when I first started out I had everything in one section too - then all this PITA about reloading dynamically caused me to separate them into sections where possible. Glad I could help!